# phpmyadmin : Depends: php-twig (>= 2.9) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed. WHAT?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, twig, mariadb

I need help figuring out what's wrong. I want to install phpmyadmin on a server to import a wordpress DB but when I install it I have a problem with php-twig

I install phpmyadmin :

```
debian@XXX:~$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php-twig (>= 2.9) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I install php-twig :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-twig is already the newest version (2.6.2-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How this two sentences can be true and at the same time ?

- phpmyadmin : Depends: php-twig (>= 2.9) but 2.6.2-2 is to be installed
- php-twig is already the newest version (2.6.2-2).

What I have missing ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 41):

You have to use backports repository (https://wiki.debian.org/Backports):

```
aptitude -t buster-backports install php-twig
```

then, you can install phpmyadmin with:

```
apt install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score -3):

Installing from source is easier and more efficient. I use this tuto : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-from-source-debian-10

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue, didn't find how to install php-twig 2.9, so I finally followed steps described here to install it from source : https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/debian/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-debian-10.html